# springboot2.7.5 start error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

I introduced the spring-boot-starter-web, used its own spring-boot-starter-logging framework, specified the configuration file in yaml, and reported startup errors
yaml:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    com.felix.flink.tutorial.api: debug
  config: classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-tutorial-component</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

exception:

```
23:45:33.009 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@7abaedae
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:299)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.felix.flink.tutorial.api.FlinkTutorialApiApplication.main(FlinkTutorialApiApplication.java:15)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 22 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i have import slf4j 2.0.3 derect in the pom,but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

SLF4J drastically changed the way its implementations are found between versions 1.x and 2.x. In 1.x, the binding class needed to provide a class named `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` - the class that's missing. In 2.x it uses the `ServiceLoader` mechanism.

Spring Boot currently still uses SLF4J 1.7.36, through `spring-boot-starter-web` -> `spring-boot-starter` -> `spring-boot-starter-logging`. The latter depends on some SLF4J bridges, as well as `logback-classic` which in turn depends on SLF4J 1.7.32. I think that the 1.7.36 "wins" over the 1.7.32.

Unless one of your other dependencies has a transitive dependency on SLF4J 2.x, everything should work just fine. If you do, then you have a mix of SLF4J 1.x and 2.x, and that's simply not going to work. Replace the 2.x dependency with a 1.x dependency and you should be fine (unless you use the fluent API that was added in 2.x).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I set <slf4j.version>2.0.3</slf4j.version><logback.version>1.4.4</logback.version> in root pom properties, which cause the situation in the appeal answer. It worked fine after  the properties removed

Comment: @felixbupt in this case you're overwriting the logback version provided by Spring Boot with one that works with SLF4J 2.x. Since the only incompatibility between the two logback versions is the SLF4J API version, you should indeed be good to go.